# How to add 48 hours or 2 days to a Date timestamp in html

Tags: html, angular, date

I want to add to a Date timestamp 48 hours or 2 Days in html.

E.g. 04.10.2019 + 2days = 06.10.2019.
I don't know if this is possible with html.

Here is that part of my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let date of dateValues">
        <td>{{date.startDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{date.endDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `date.startDate` is of type Date.

The `date.endDate` is of type Date too.

I'm want to do something like this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let date of dateValues">
            <td>{{date.startDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{date.endDate =(date.startDate + 2days) |date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I would appreciate any suggestion of how to do this, or any source to read about it.

Comment: Why are you not doing this in the component (instead of the template)?

Comment: @Igor I thought maybe there is a short way to do it in html. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wouldn't be "in HTML" that you would accomplish this, it would be something you do in TypeScript/JavaScript. (That stuff you see inside the `{{...}}` is Angular-modified JavaScript being executed, not HTML.)

And as @Igor mentioned in a comment, it's better to do this inside the component, not try to do it in the template, because doing this right is a bit more code than you'd want to stick into a template.

The quick-and-dirty-way to add two days to a date would be like this:

`let twoDaysLater = new Date(originalDate.getTime() + 2 * 86400 * 1000);`

That works well in most cases, but can be off by an hour (and possibly cause a shift of a day if the time is near midnight) if Daylight Saving Time starts or ends within that two day span.

Comment: thank you, I will do it in the TypeScript file :)